# Insert query not working as expected in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my create table query.

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BRANDS + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER UNIQUE,"
    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
    + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"
    + KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

This is function for updating/adding new brand.

```
void addBrand(Brand brand) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, brand.getId()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_NAME, brand.getName()); // Contact Name


    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_BRANDS +
                    " SET " + KEY_NAME + " = ?, " +
                    KEY_UPDATED_AT + " = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                    " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new Object[]{brand.getName(), brand.getId()});


    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_BRANDS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);        
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

while calling i am passing id and name explicitly like this.

```
db.addBrand(new Brand(17, "sdddddsfsfdsfdshfjdh"));
```

The problem is  addBrand () is not adding brand_id, that i am passing. It is adding a sequential value (1, 2 3 4) instead of that??

Why is this behaviour? How to fix that?

As per my understanding if i am not having a column with primary key sqlite will add a column its own to identify row. Am i wrong?

Comment: What does your `Brand` class look like?

Comment: int id; String name; and getter, setter for those two.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `new Object[]`with `new String[]` and use [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
db.update(TABLE_BRANDS, values, "WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = ? ... etc", new String[]{brand.getName(), brand.getId()})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i shall use update you suggested then what should i pass for "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: just add it to your Content Values

Comment: Can you tell me how? As i know The ContentValues object allows only literal values.

Comment: Don't know the format in which SQLite stores it's timestamp (String/Integer), google it ;). And then just add is as a literal value to your content values.

Comment: Issue is with insert not update. After commenting UPDATE portion i called this db.addBrand(new Brand(18, "ABCD")); but its adding (9 ABCD)

Comment: sounds like you mixed up your constants, run the debugger and check your ContentValue object

Answer (score 0):

You get an [autoincrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) only when it is declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
UNIQUE does not suffice.

Comment: True that. and even i don't want to create  auto incrementing column. But the above column is behaving like a auto incrementing column. Whatever the brand ID i pass to it its gets converted into sequential increment number.